Uniqueness of the $A$-scheme structure on $\operatorname{Proj} B$
Let $B$ be a graded $A$-algebra, and consider the topological space $X:=\operatorname{Proj} B$.
Call $(X,O_X)$ the usual structure of scheme on $X$. It is a structure of $A$-scheme as well, because $O_X(X)=B_0$, and the structure of $A$-algebra on $B$ gives a ring map $A\to B_0$.
I don't understand why $(X,O_X)$ is the only structure of $A$-scheme on $X$ that  restricted to any $D_+(f)$, with any $f\in B_+$ homogeneus, is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}B_{(f)}$ over $A$.
($A\to B\to B_f$ factors via $ l_f:A\to B_{(f)}$, giving a structure of $A$-scheme to $\operatorname{Spec}B_{(f)}$).
Let's take a sheaf $O$ on $X$ such that $(X,O)$ is an $A$-scheme with the italic property, and let's  check that $O$ is isomorphic to $O_X$.
First, the data that $(X,O)$ is an $A$-scheme amounts to a ring map $A\to O(X)$.
Let $f\in B_+$ homogeneus. $(D_+(f),O|_{D_+(f)})$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}B_{(f)}$ over $A$ means:

$O_X(D_+(f)\cong B_{(f)}$ and
$A\to O(X)\xrightarrow{_{\mathrm{restr}}}O(D_+(f))\cong B_{(f)}$ is equal to $l_f$.

This part agrees with the usual definition of $\mathcal O_X$, where we set $O_X(D_+(f))=B_{(f)}$; we should only prove that the isomorphisms in point 1 are natural, i.e. compatible with the restrictions.
Let $f,g\in B_+$ homogeneus, and assume $D_+(g)\subset D_+(f)$. The restriction of $O_X$ is the unique $B_0$-algebra map $B_{(f)}\to B_{(g)}$. The only thing we know about the restriction $O(D_+(f))\to O(D_+(g))$, instead, is that it is an $A$-algebra map, with the obvious structures of $A\to O(X)\to O(D_+(f))$ and $A\to O(X)\to O(D_+(g))$.
Translating via isomorphisms, my issue amounts to prove that the unique $B_0$-algebra map $B_{(f)}\to B_{(g)}$ is also the unique $A$-algebra map, with structures given by $l_f,l_g$. However this fact doesn't seem true to me.
I tried to state the problem as clear as I could, I hope that it is comprehensible. Thanks for any help.

$\mathcal O_X(X)=B_0$ is not always true. Consider the projective subscheme in $\mathbb P^1$ given by $x^2-xy$ which is $\operatorname{Proj} k[x,y]/\langle x^2-xy \rangle$

@user6 I was convinced that $O_X(X)$ was in fact $B_0$, thanks! I was convinced so because, distractedly, I thought that the parts (a), (b) and (c) of Proposition 3.36 in Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry were true for any homogeneous $f$, and not only for those in $B_+$. Do you confirm that it is not the case? (I ask because if you say that those three results of 3.36 holds for any homogeneous $f$ in general, I would have a proof that $O_X(X)=B_0$ which I can't see why it is wrong). Thanks again

okay, after a brief glance, let's say $B= k[x,y]$ with the usual grading. Consider $f=1\in B_0$. Then $D^+(f)=\operatorname{Proj}k[x,y]$ which is $\mathbb P^1$ and $\operatorname {Spec} B_{(f)} $ is $\operatorname {Spec} k$ which is a point.

@user6 thanks for the example, very simple an convincing

I think there may be some confusion around what "the structure of an $A$-scheme" means. To me, if $A$ is a ring, the structure of an $A$-scheme on $X$ is a morphism $\varphi:X\to\operatorname{Spec} A$, so I would interpret the statement you're trying to prove as "there is a unique morphism $\varphi:X\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ so that the restriction $\varphi|_{D_+(f)}: D_+(f)\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is isomorphic to the usual map $\operatorname{Spec} B_{(f)}\to\operatorname{Spec} A$".
This is not so bad: the unique map $X\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the result of gluing the standard maps $\operatorname{Spec} B_{(f)}\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ as $f$ runs over the homogeneous elements of positive degree of $B$.

If, as you say, the scheme structure on $X$ is fixed as the standard one and we need to show that there is a unique morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}A$, there would be no problems. I thought we needed to show that also the scheme structure on $X$ is unique, instead of considering it fixed already

I mean, even if I know that any $D_+(f)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}B_{(f)}$, if I don't have some coherence conditions satisfied I can't say that the scheme structure on $X$ is the standard one right?

Anyway, if you want to check that the meaning is the one you are guessing, this question is referred to Proposition 3.38 in Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry

It turns out that Liu does things a little different than I'd expect. I've left an answer over at your other question asked after this one, which should address the issue.
